# qt : expandable/collapsable listview

Tags: qt, expandablelistview, qlistview

I hope to create a "NEW" listview like **[QML Exmaple](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/declarative-modelviews-listview-expandingdelegates.html)** with native Qt classes.

Exactly I want to make a listview which works like below.

[image]
[image]

It looks like a QML example but slightly differs. QListView has a limitation for it's layout, right? I want a hint for overcoming the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use `GridView` instead of `ListView`. That'll get you a step closer to making your UI look like what you have designed. However currently Qt Quick only supports fixed cell sizes of grid items, which means you won't be able to expand the cell size of just one item. All you *can* do is set up the cell size to fit the expanded item so that every grid item will take up as much space as it could possibly need. Then you can alter the dimensions of each item without worrying about fitting issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. To create my **listview** I'd rather use Qt Quick. I have to find a way to interact between Qt Quick  and Python :)

Comment: Qt Quick applications are meant to work in QML/C++. Why Python?

Comment: Does not Qt Quick work with Python? I can use QDeclarativeView in PyQt or Pyside, right? I meant to create a QML file and use it in QDeclarativeView. Because I'm familiar with Python that C++, so I've used PyQt.

Comment: Well I suppose if you want to use third party bindings that's okay too, but it's out of the scope of this question =).